# vb.net StringBetween Function Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need a stringbetween function. But function should be Array.

Ex : 
p1 and p2 some text .

Mystring = "bla bla bla **StartText** bla bla bla bal **EndText** bla bla **StartText** bla bla **EndText**  "

This function is ;

```
dim BetweenStrings as Array 

BetweenStrings = _GetStringBetween(Mystring,"StartText","EndText")

BetweenStrings(1) ---> bla bla bla bla

BetweenStrings(2) ---> bla bla
```

For all StartText and EndText between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RegEx would be an excellent choice, as Jim Wooley demonstrated.  However, if you are looking for a non-regex solution, this should work:

```
Private Function _GetStringBetween(ByVal text As String, ByVal startTag As String, ByVal endTag As String) As String()
    Dim results As New List(Of String)()
    While text.Length <> 0
        Dim startIndex As Integer = text.IndexOf(startTag)
        If startIndex <> -1 Then
            text = text.Substring(startIndex + startTag.Length)
            Dim endIndex As Integer = text.IndexOf(endTag)
            If endIndex <> -1 Then
                results.Add(text.Substring(0, endIndex))
                text = text.Substring(endIndex + endTag.Length)
            Else
                Exit While
            End If
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
    Return results.ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into regular expressions for string matches. For example from your input string, you could do something like the following:

```
Dim regexString = "StartText(?<found>[^EndText]+)"
Dim matches = Regex.Match(MyString, regexString)
For Each match in matches
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups("found").Value)
Next
```